# Can't get Android studio to run a app on an emulator

Tags: java, android

Three days ago, I started to try out Android development. I've installed Android Studio 2.2.3 on a VMWare instance (didn't work), on a Win7 bare metal machine (dual quad, 64gb RAM), a Ubuntu bare metal machine (similar specs), a CentOS 7 machine (similar specs), and on a Summer 2009 iMac.

I've removed and reinstalled Android studio on the Win 7 machine as an Admin, as a non-Admin 2-3 times each. On every deployment I get the same errors. The "Hello World App" (default app from Android's site and an online tutorial) appears to compile correctly, the android emulator comes up, but the process freezes and times out on all of the above implementations. I've looked at the logs and see horrific error messages, saying files don't exist, permissions denied, failed to create fonts, modules not found, etc.

This is from fresh installs on 5 different platforms indicated above. The last time I reinstalled, I installed every component, add on, and api, etc. the install procedure would allow.

I do **not** have a android device, nor will I purchase one, given the problems I've had trying to develop an app for one.

Are there **specific** settings for a **specific** Android version, and **specifics** that must be set to get things to work? One thousand error messages on a default app, on a fresh install is NOT very encouraging. I don't have a clue as to where to start. I've looked through Stack Overflow many times and tried many of the suggestions, and still cannot get an app running on an emulator. I've tried 8-10 different emulator images and am ready to throw in the towel.

```
01-25 21:17:06.028 0-1174/? E/cutils: Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
01-25 21:17:07.177 1160-1160/? E/lowmemorykiller: Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer

                                              -

-------- beginning of system
01-25 21:17:07.913 1163-1163/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
01-25 21:17:09.756 1163-1163/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-25 21:17:09.964 1163-1163/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:17:11.055 1163-1229/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-25 21:17:15.787 1273-1286/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
01-25 21:17:16.133 1273-1286/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)

[ 01-25 21:17:16.156  1163: 1233 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb6915040, tid 1233
01-25 21:17:16.274 1173-1173/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
01-25 21:17:16.279 1173-1371/? E/AudioFlinger: no wake lock to update!
01-25 21:17:16.362 1173-1173/? E/AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
01-25 21:17:16.364 1173-1173/? E/SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)

[ 01-25 21:17:17.032  1163: 1229 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb6b0d070, tid 1229
01-25 21:17:19.061 1169-1169/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -N oem_nat_pre 
01-25 21:17:19.510 1169-1169/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j oem_nat_pre 
01-25 21:17:20.529 1169-1169/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -N natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING 
01-25 21:17:20.765 1169-1169/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING 
01-25 21:17:24.872 1169-1169/? E/BandwidthController: runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
01-25 21:17:24.967 1169-1169/? E/BandwidthController: runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
01-25 21:17:27.573 1176-1176/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-25 21:17:27.574 1176-1176/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujaratiUI-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujaratiUI-Bold.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhi-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhi-Bold.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.896 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Bold.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.910 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.910 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansSinhala-Bold.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.920 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansCherokee-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.920 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansCanadianAboriginal-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.920 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf
01-25 21:17:28.920 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansHans-Regular.otf
01-25 21:17:28.920 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansHant-Regular.otf
01-25 21:17:28.920 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansJP-Regular.otf
01-25 21:17:28.920 1176-1176/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansKR-Regular.otf
01-25 21:17:31.585 1176-1176/? E/EmojiFactory_jni: Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
01-25 21:17:52.136 1176-1176/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
01-25 21:17:54.267 1615-1615/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/services.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@services.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:17:54.455 1615-1615/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:17:56.079 1618-1618/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/ethernet-service.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@ethernet-service.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:17:56.132 1618-1618/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:17:56.174 1619-1619/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/wifi-service.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@wifi-service.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:17:56.291 1619-1619/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:17:56.863 1174-1174/? E/installd: eof
01-25 21:17:56.863 1174-1174/? E/installd: failed to read size
01-25 21:18:01.073 1597-1597/system_process E/PowerManagerService-JNI: Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
01-25 21:18:01.890 1163-1229/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-25 21:18:03.551 1648-1648/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/android.test.runner.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@android.test.runner.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:03.780 1648-1648/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:03.852 1649-1649/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/com.android.future.usb.accessory.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:03.917 1649-1649/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:04.857 1652-1652/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/com.android.media.remotedisplay.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:04.904 1652-1652/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:04.935 1653-1653/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/com.android.location.provider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@com.android.location.provider.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:05.055 1653-1653/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:05.099 1654-1654/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/javax.obex.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@javax.obex.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:05.150 1654-1654/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:05.295 1657-1657/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/com.google.android.media.effects.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@com.google.android.media.effects.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:05.345 1657-1657/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:06.249 1658-1658/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/com.google.android.maps.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@com.google.android.maps.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:06.307 1658-1658/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:06.362 1659-1659/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/com.android.mediadrm.signer.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@com.android.mediadrm.signer.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:06.411 1659-1659/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:06.687 1662-1662/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/am.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@am.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:06.989 1662-1662/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:07.173 1663-1663/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/appops.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@appops.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:07.213 1663-1663/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:07.243 1664-1664/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/appwidget.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@appwidget.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:07.575 1664-1664/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:07.827 1665-1665/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/bmgr.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@bmgr.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:08.002 1665-1665/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:08.208 1668-1668/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/bu.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@bu.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:08.418 1668-1668/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:08.902 1669-1669/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/content.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@content.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:09.405 1669-1669/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:09.724 1672-1672/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/dpm.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@dpm.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:09.757 1672-1672/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:10.076 1673-1673/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/ime.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@ime.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:10.195 1673-1673/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:10.507 1676-1676/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/input.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@input.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:10.671 1676-1676/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:10.867 1677-1677/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/media_cmd.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@media_cmd.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:10.982 1677-1677/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:11.053 1678-1678/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/monkey.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@monkey.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:11.088 1678-1678/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:11.436 1679-1679/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/pm.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@pm.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:11.586 1679-1679/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:11.695 1682-1682/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/requestsync.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@requestsync.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:11.747 1682-1682/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:11.814 1683-1683/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/settings.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@settings.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:11.855 1683-1683/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:11.913 1684-1684/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/svc.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@svc.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:11.956 1684-1684/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:12.086 1685-1685/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/uiautomator.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@uiautomator.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:12.125 1685-1685/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:18:12.194 1686-1686/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/framework/x86/wm.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@wm.jar@classes.dex)
01-25 21:18:12.238 1686-1686/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:21.657 1793-1793/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/KeyChain/x86/KeyChain.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@KeyChain@KeyChain.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:21.694 1793-1793/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:21.716 1794-1794/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/SettingsProvider/x86/SettingsProvider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@SettingsProvider@SettingsProvider.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:21.777 1794-1794/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:21.799 1795-1795/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/Settings/x86/Settings.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@Settings@Settings.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:21.841 1795-1795/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:21.924 1796-1796/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/FusedLocation/x86/FusedLocation.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@FusedLocation@FusedLocation.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:21.965 1796-1796/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:21.983 1797-1797/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/InputDevices/x86/InputDevices.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@InputDevices@InputDevices.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:22.024 1797-1797/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:22.106 1800-1800/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/GoogleLoginService/x86/GoogleLoginService.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@GoogleLoginService@GoogleLoginService.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:22.201 1800-1800/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:22.288 1801-1801/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework/x86/GoogleServicesFramework.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@GoogleServicesFramework@GoogleServicesFramework.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:22.322 1801-1801/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:24.091 1597-1597/system_process E/ConsumerIrService: Can't open consumer IR HW Module, error: -2
01-25 21:19:25.197 1597-1810/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
01-25 21:19:47.405 1836-1836/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/SystemUI/x86/SystemUI.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@SystemUI@SystemUI.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:47.442 1162-1837/? E/fstrim: FITRIM ioctl failed on /cache (error 95/Operation not supported on transport endpoint)
01-25 21:19:47.442 1162-1837/? E/fstrim: FITRIM ioctl failed on /data (error 95/Operation not supported on transport endpoint)
01-25 21:19:47.560 1836-1836/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:50.769 1842-1842/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/TelephonyProvider/x86/TelephonyProvider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@TelephonyProvider@TelephonyProvider.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:51.028 1842-1842/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:51.557 1845-1845/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/LatinIME/x86/LatinIME.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@LatinIME@LatinIME.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:51.721 1845-1845/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:53.751 1850-1850/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/TeleService/x86/TeleService.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@TeleService@TeleService.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:54.122 1850-1850/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:54.649 1853-1853/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/Shell/x86/Shell.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@Shell@Shell.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:54.946 1853-1853/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:55.491 1854-1854/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/ProxyHandler/x86/ProxyHandler.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@ProxyHandler@ProxyHandler.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:55.782 1854-1854/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:56.021 1855-1855/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/DefaultContainerService/x86/DefaultContainerService.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@DefaultContainerService@DefaultContainerService.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:56.152 1855-1855/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:56.363 1858-1858/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/Dialer/x86/Dialer.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@Dialer@Dialer.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:56.832 1858-1858/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:19:59.042 1863-1863/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/Telecom/x86/Telecom.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@Telecom@Telecom.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:19:59.570 1863-1863/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:00.563 1866-1866/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/MmsService/x86/MmsService.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@MmsService@MmsService.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:00.870 1866-1866/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:01.074 1869-1869/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/ManagedProvisioning/x86/ManagedProvisioning.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@ManagedProvisioning@ManagedProvisioning.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:01.402 1869-1869/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:01.829 1870-1870/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/MediaProvider/x86/MediaProvider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@MediaProvider@MediaProvider.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:02.002 1870-1870/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:02.433 1873-1873/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/ContactsProvider/x86/ContactsProvider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@ContactsProvider@ContactsProvider.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:02.770 1873-1873/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:03.435 1876-1876/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/CalendarProvider/x86/CalendarProvider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@CalendarProvider@CalendarProvider.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:03.732 1876-1876/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:04.365 1877-1877/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/LiveWallpapersPicker/x86/LiveWallpapersPicker.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@LiveWallpapersPicker@LiveWallpapersPicker.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:04.580 1877-1877/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:04.652 1880-1880/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/UserDictionaryProvider/x86/UserDictionaryProvider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@UserDictionaryProvider@UserDictionaryProvider.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:04.891 1880-1880/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:05.322 1881-1881/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/SharedStorageBackup/x86/SharedStorageBackup.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@SharedStorageBackup@SharedStorageBackup.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:05.399 1881-1881/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:05.572 1882-1882/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/OpenWnn/x86/OpenWnn.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@OpenWnn@OpenWnn.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:05.951 1882-1882/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:06.343 1885-1885/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/PackageInstaller/x86/PackageInstaller.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@PackageInstaller@PackageInstaller.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:06.375 1885-1885/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:06.578 1886-1886/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/Contacts/x86/Contacts.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@Contacts@Contacts.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:06.797 1886-1886/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:08.492 1892-1892/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/EmulatorSmokeTests/x86/EmulatorSmokeTests.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@EmulatorSmokeTests@EmulatorSmokeTests.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:08.586 1892-1892/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:09.276 1893-1893/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/Exchange2/x86/Exchange2.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@Exchange2@Exchange2.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:09.680 1893-1893/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:13.034 1908-1908/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/DownloadProviderUi/x86/DownloadProviderUi.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@DownloadProviderUi@DownloadProviderUi.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:13.224 1908-1908/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:13.735 1911-1911/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/SpeechRecorder/x86/SpeechRecorder.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@SpeechRecorder@SpeechRecorder.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:13.875 1911-1911/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:14.102 1912-1912/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/Calendar/x86/Calendar.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@Calendar@Calendar.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:14.241 1912-1912/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:15.774 1917-1917/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/Maps/x86/Maps.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@Maps@Maps.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:16.053 1917-1917/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:30.882 1938-1938/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/Gallery/x86/Gallery.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@Gallery@Gallery.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:31.061 1938-1938/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:31.385 1939-1939/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/PicoTts/x86/PicoTts.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@PicoTts@PicoTts.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:31.588 1939-1939/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:32.095 1942-1942/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/ExternalStorageProvider/x86/ExternalStorageProvider.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@ExternalStorageProvider@ExternalStorageProvider.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:32.190 1942-1942/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:32.467 1943-1943/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/DocumentsUI/x86/DocumentsUI.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@DocumentsUI@DocumentsUI.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:32.600 1943-1943/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:33.563 1946-1946/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/app/BasicDreams/x86/BasicDreams.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@BasicDreams@BasicDreams.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:34.151 1946-1946/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 21:20:34.266 1949-1949/? E/installd: Running /system/bin/patchoat isa=x86 in-fd=5 (/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/x86/PrebuiltGmsCore.odex) out-fd=6 (/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@priv-app@PrebuiltGmsCore@PrebuiltGmsCore.apk@classes.dex)
01-25 21:20:34.960 1949-1949/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created several other virtual devices/emulators similar to this... (Marshmallow)  and they all fail. As you said, just three clicks and Voila, all of the above error messages.

Gradle says the app compiled correctly, the emulator pops up, then nothing ( I see "android" in white letters and it freezes). I've never seen "Hello World" in the emulator.

Often the emulator can''t be closed, and often the IDE and Win 7 completely locks up. Sometimes I see a some messages that say something like 12 of 17 xxxxx loaded. in the emulator but nothing afterwards.

Look at all the error messages I get from doing EXACTLY what  you suggested, what Android's "Getting Started" guide says, and an online tutorial suggests.  On 5 different platforms.

File permissions, files missing, modules not found, fonts that can't install, and a basket full of other errors. Android Studio apparently works under specific instances (certain hardware and software), and doesn't work under a LOT of specific instances (hardware, OSes, and software).

and what is E/cutils-trace,  E/installd, E/libEGL, E/BandwidthController, E/android.os.Debug. E/memtrack, E/Netd, etc. It looks like files within a file system that are NOT on a Windows machine. Are they files on an android device's OS??? I believe these error messages are coming from the emulator as they appear in the "Android Monitor tab.

Here's another error I keep getting when I try to run the emulator BEFORE I try to run my app as some have suggested.

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\arbian33.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_21.avd/cache.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\arbian33.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_21.avd/cache.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_21.avd/cache.img': Invalid argument

I've been in IT 30+ years and have NEVER seen something puke its guts out like this on a default installation and a simple "Hello World" program.

Comment: I'm finding out the problem is with the emulator images. I jacked up the memory on all of the settings, and have run the emulators from the command line, and watched the "Android Monitor". All of the aforementioned errors are coming from the emulator trying to start-up.   I've tried the latest "devices" and they crash also. 

The emulator now says: 

Process system isn't responding
X Close app
@ Wait